# Want to add new properies in ListItem Collection

Tags: asp.net, properties, collections, listitem

I am working on to create a custom control inherited by CheckboxList control. We can add items from ListItem collection editior at the design time. In this ListItem Collection editor there are 4 properties 

1) Enabled 
2) Selected
3) Text
4) value
I really need to add some new properties such as "ImageURL" and "IsClear". Do you have any ideas/methods or magic to add these properties.

I need Expert's opinion from StackOverFlow.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that inherits from ListItem to add the properties.  But inheriting from CheckBoxList would use the ListItem base type... You could try shadowing the Items collection to use your custom type, though I don't know that will work the same way... it depends where you need to use these new properties of the list item.

HTH.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "This class can not be inherited."

Comment: Thanks.  You could create your own class with it's own collection of items, and this would work too.  Just more work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a User Control?  You can define public members in the code behind that will then be accessible when you define the control on you aspx page.

Your aspx page would have something like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyCustomControls" Namespace="MyCustomControls" TagPrefix="cust" %>
...
<cust:MyCheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server" imageURL="http://blah.com/1.jpg" isClear="false />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListItem` class has the `Attributes` property. Use it. You'll find there any additional attributes specified for `asp:listitem` in the mark-up that are not mapped to the properties.